Jenkins Secret with Special Characters Gets Truncated in Shell Script
I'm facing an issue with Jenkins where a secret containing special characters (specifically $ and =) gets truncated when used in a shell script. Here are the details:
I have a secret in Jenkins that stores the following string:
111111-d032-40bd-b87d1153a9430e92$fmN1pdifFkespherhHjIO70KjIzZfqjevCGY3kAbxjU=

I am using this secret in my Jenkins pipeline like this:
string(credentialsId: "${env.PREFIX}-mes-client-secret", variable: 'MYSECRET'),
sh "echo MYSECRET ='$MYSECRET' >> ${env.ENV_FILE}"

However, when I check the output in my .env file, the string gets truncated at the $ and replaced with =
I suspect Jenkins is misinterpreting the $ as a variable substitution. How can I ensure the secret is correctly passed into my shell script without truncation or alteration?
What I've Tried:
Changing double quotes to single quotes around the credentialsId, but this doesn't seem to work as expected.
Looking for ways to escape the $ in the secret, but I haven't found a solution that works.
Environment:
Jenkins version: latest
Pipeline type: Declarative
Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

You define variable MYSECRET and then use MES_CLIENT_SECRET. And then the file doesn't match your sh command. Could you edit your question to be a bit more consistent?

it's typo, sorry! i updated question! i use correct name!

First you may want to take a look at the pipeline syntax.
this issue is related to how Jenkins handles strings containing special characters, especially the $, which it interprets for variable substitution. To prevent Jenkins from misinterpreting your secret, you can try the following approaches:
1- Escaping the Dollar Sign
string(credentialsId: "${env.PREFIX}-mes-client-secret", variable: 'MYSECRET'),
sh "echo MYSECRET ='\\$MYSECRET' >> ${env.ENV_FILE}"


2- Using Single Quotes
string(credentialsId: "${env.PREFIX}-mes-client-secret", variable: 'MYSECRET'),
sh 'echo MYSECRET ="$MYSECRET" >> ${env.ENV_FILE}'

3- Secure Credentials Handling and Contextual Execution
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "${env.PREFIX}-mes-client-secret", variable: 'MYSECRET')]) {
    dir("/<your directory>/") {
        add_secret_to_file = sh (
            returnStdout: true,
            script: """
                echo MYSECRET ='\\$MYSECRET' >> ${env.ENV_FILE}
            """
        )
    }
}

or
withCredentials([string(credentialsId: "${env.PREFIX}-mes-client-secret", variable: 'MYSECRET')]) {
    dir("/<your directory>/") {
        add_secret_to_file = sh (
            returnStdout: true,
            script: """
                echo MYSECRET = $MYSECRET >> ${env.ENV_FILE}
            """
        )
    }
}

